# BUG: Unable to handle kernel paging request at error for the sample kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, ioctl

I am writing a sample kernel module which reads data sent through ioctl call from application and prints them.

I am passing structure "ioctl_struct" through ioctl from the application and in the kernel module, I will be printing its member variables.

this works absolutely fine in a few machines. In a few machines

> > "BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at"

the error is thrown while accessing "name and testStruct's id1 and id2".

I don't think this module is hardware/kernel dependent.
I am not sure where it's going wrong. any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Driver.c kernel module

```
static const char DEVICE_NAME[]="testipc";
static struct proc_dir_entry * proc_ipc = NULL;

struct test
{
        int id1;
        int id2;
};

struct ioctl_struct
{
    __user struct test *testStruct;
    __user int * id;
    __user char * name;
        int cmd;
};


static int __init etx_driver_init(void);
static void __exit etx_driver_exit(void);
static long etx_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);

static struct file_operations fops =
{
        .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
        .read           = etx_read,
        .write          = etx_write,
        .open           = etx_open,
        .unlocked_ioctl = etx_ioctl,
        .release        = etx_release,
        .unlocked_ioctl = etx_ioctl,
};


static long etx_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    printk("reached ioctl....\n");
    struct ioctl_struct   buf;

         if (copy_from_user(&buf, (void *)arg, sizeof(buf)))
        return -EFAULT;

    printk("succes..2\n");
    printk("id %d\n",buf.id);
    printk("cmd %d\n",buf.cmd);
    printk("filename %s\n",buf.name);
    printk("token %d\n",buf.testStruct->id1);
    printk("token %d\n",buf.testStruct->id2);
        return 0;
}


static int __init etx_driver_init(void)
{
    printk("new test driver loaded..");
        proc_ipc = proc_create(DEVICE_NAME, 0, NULL, &fops);
        if (!proc_ipc)
        {
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Unable to create /proc/%s\n", DEVICE_NAME);
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;

}

void __exit etx_driver_exit(void)
{
          if (proc_ipc)
                proc_remove(proc_ipc);

        proc_ipc = NULL;

}

module_init(etx_driver_init);
module_exit(etx_driver_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("lin");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple driver");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
```

and following is my application file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
# define __user 

static int fd=NULL;

#define TEST_IOCTL _IOWR('z', 80, struct ioctl_struct)

struct test
{
    int id1;
    int id2;
};

struct ioctl_struct
{
    __user struct test *testStruct;
    __user int * id;
    __user char * name;
    int cmd;
};

void init()
{
        printf("\nOpening Driver\n");
        fd = open("/proc/testipc", O_RDWR);
        if(fd < 0) {
                printf("Cannot open device file...\n");
                return 0;
        }
}

void send()
{
    int id=5;
    int *pid=id;    
    char name[10]={'H','e','l','l','o'};
    struct test testStruct;
    testStruct.id1=44;
    testStruct.id2=33;

    struct ioctl_struct request;
    request.name = name ;
    request.id = pid;
    request.cmd = 33;
    request.testStruct = &testStruct;
    ioctl(fd, TEST_IOCTL, &request);
}

void finish()
{
        printf("Closing Driver\n");
        close(fd);
}

int main()
{
    init();
    send();
    finish();
    return 0;
}
```

In dmesg, 
id 5,
cmd 33,
Hello,
44,
33,
should be printed

Comment: The structure's field `testStruct` is a **pointer to user space data**, but your code dereferences this pointer *directly*, without required `copy_from_user` or similar.

Comment: I am using copy_from_user for "ioctl_struct's buf".
 Is that copy_from_user  function call needed for each user pointer?

Comment: You should **never** dereference pointers to user-space data. Even if you have "checked" these data before (with `copy_from_user`), the data can be unmapped after that check, so accessing it would cause a page fault. While such page fault is harmless for user space code (the data would be mapped again), the Linux kernel doesn't try to resolve page fault caused by its code.

Comment: copied name and testStruct to temp variables by using copy_from_user and then printed. this worked for me.
How come this issue I have seen it in a few machines, any idea? because the above code worked in many machines without an issue.

Comment: Probably, this is related with unmapping the memory. It is rare to find the memory unmapped, if it is accessed just before system call. But this is still possible. As I said before, kernel cannot work with page fault caused by temporary unmapped memory. But `copy_from_user` works correctly in this case.